# Data section size in "size" command on Mac

Tags: linux, macos, size, osx-leopard, unix

Given the following output of the "size" command on Mac OS X 10.5 on an small executable, what is the value under __DATA? Is it the uninitialized data segment size or initialized data segment size? What I find confounding is that this value (nor the rest of the values) does not seem to change whether I initialize (the one and only) global array in the program or not.

I guess this command works differently on Linux and Mac?

```
__TEXT  __DATA  __OBJC  others  dec hex
4096    4096    0   4294971392  4294979584  100003000
```

Comment: If you initialize the global array to `{0}`, it will probably still live in the BSS. Try initializing it to `{1}`.

Comment: what does it mean that the total decimal size is 4294979584? 4GB?

Answer (score 1):

On linux, the format is

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1281     520      32    1833     729 a.out
```

`BSS` is the size in bytes of the zero initialized globals and local statics. I verified and they(data, bss etc) are changing appropriately with change in the number of variables and their initialized values.

One thing to note is, `size` without any parameters automatically chooses `a.out` in the CWD.

I am totally unaware of things in Mac. My guess is `__OBJC` = `BSS` . Also check how are you invoking the `size` command

Answer (score 1):

All statics and globals are initialized, it's just a question of whether they are initialized to zero or some other value.  Variables initialized to zero go into the __bss *section* of the __DATA *segment*.  Other variables will go into other sections of the __DATA segment.